# Differential Equation/Recurrence Relation with matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf D$ be a $3\times 3$ diagonal matrix, and $\boldsymbol x_n(t)=(x_n(t), y_n(t), z_n(t))$.

I am familiar with how to solve equations given by a differential equation $\dot{\boldsymbol x}(t)=\mathbf D\boldsymbol x$ or a reccurence relation $\boldsymbol x_{n+1}=\mathbf D\boldsymbol x_n$, but what I am given here is something which is both, namely $\dot{\boldsymbol x}_{n+1}=\mathbf D\boldsymbol x_n$. More concretely, we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}\dot x_{n+1}(t)\\\dot y_{n+1}(t)\\\dot z_{n+1}(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2 x_n(t)\\3y_n(t)\\4 y_n(t) \end{pmatrix}.$$

Assuming some initial $\boldsymbol x_0(t)$, all I can deduce about $x_n$, say, is that $x_{n}=2^n\underbrace{\int\dots\int}_n x_0(t)\,dt^n$. Can I get a more concrete answer, or is this all that is possible?

Usually when the problem is either one or the other, we get explicit formulae such as $x_n=2^n x_0$ or $x(t) = 2c_1e^{2t}-c_2e^{-2t}$ for each of the entries.